# How Can We Read Incoming SMS by using Application in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, message, messaging

In my application I am able to send an SMS programatically to a particular mobile number when the user clicks submit button.  Then there is a response message from that mobile number now I want to read that message and populate that SMS text in to my application.

I searched for this and found that this is not possible in iOS.
My question is there any possibility accessing inbox SMS with user permissions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simply two words from Apple:

> Not Possible

**Detailed:**

An iOS app can only access the data for which Apple supplies a documented public API. iOS can not access outside of the sandbox until Apple provides a public API for it. So intercepting/reading an incoming SMS not possible. And no idea when the iOS device is jailbroken.

Comment: Actually those are 2 words :D

Answer (score 5):

**No** it's not possible in iOS, it's possible on jailbroken devices but you can not place your application in the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read SMS, but you can auto fill a text field from SMS.

From Apple Documentation :

> To ensure your text input view displays the right AutoFill
>   suggestions, set the textContentType property on any relevant input
>   views.

so you can do the following :

```
textField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

More info : 
[check the link here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view)