# Can I access to SMS inbox in new version of iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios8

In previous versions of iOS we didn't access to short messages inbox.
New version of iOS released, now have we access to inbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO** this is still not possible.  Check out `Adam Davis`'s answer on [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone) this still remains the same.

Apps will still work in a sandbox in iOS8 so they will not know about other apps and will not be able to access their content. This is how Apple has always had it and I very much doubt they will change it any time soon, if they change it at all. Also check out [How Can We Read Incoming SMS by using Application in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300138/how-can-we-read-incoming-sms-by-using-application-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't have inbox system as Symbian or Android instead they use message to send and receive SMS.

Answer (score 0):

you can read message from notification whenever new incoming message arrive