# How to Read a SMS from a special number in iOS via a PC program

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I want to develop a PC program to help me handle some bank transfer requirements. For security reasons, every requirements should provide a TAN-Code which will be sent via SMS.

If the TAN-Code can be read by a program on a PC, some special transfer requirements will be easy to handle. I know that with a Android phone, this will not be a problem, but I'm not going to buy one.

Comment: Why is this tagged with c# though? Also are you asking a particular question or just asking us to provide you a solution. It's somewhat vague this 'question'.

Comment: You will not be able to do this via any official way and might require a jailbroken device. Apple does not allow access to SMS inbox.

Answer (score 0):

As better stared here [Can I access to SMS inbox in new version of iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034417/can-i-access-to-sms-inbox-in-new-version-of-ios) and in many other questions, this is not possible.