# cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions throughs error call back

Tags: cordova, angular, permissions, ionic2, ionic3

i am using android 6.0.1 i am trying to get the permissions for my default sms

here is my code to allow the permission

```
var self = this;

      var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;

        permissions.hasPermission(permissions.READ_SMS, checkPermissionCallback, null);
        self.getSMS();
        function checkPermissionCallback (status)  {
          if(!status.hasPermission) {
            var errorCallback = () => {
              alert('READ_SMS permission is not turned on');
            }

            permissions.requestPermission(
              permissions.READ_SMS,
              (status) => {

              if(!status.hasPermission) {
                errorCallback();
              }
              else{
                self.getSMS();
              }
            },
            errorCallback);
          }
        }
```

> the problem is i am always invoking only error call back
>
> self.getSms() is the function to read the sms available but i am not invoking the successcallback of the permissions

here is my config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.kmart102011" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Kmart</name>
    <description>An app which is used to contact directly deal with customer and formars.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="70000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    </feature>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics" spec="~1.7.11" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sms-plugin" spec="~0.1.11" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="~5.1.8" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="~0.1.9" />
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="~2.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" spec="~2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="~0.11.0" />
</widget>
```

here is my androidmanifest.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.ionicframework.kmart102011" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService" />
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.sharing.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/sharing_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: did you tried debugging on device console to find any error trace?

Comment: yes i tried that one `console.log(status)` shows `{hasPermission: false}` @Gandhi

Comment: is your plugin present in config.xml?

Comment: `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="~0.11.0" />` is what i got in config.xml @suraj

Comment: is the permission there in android manifest in your platform?

Comment: not config.xml .. check android manifest xml in your platform->android

Comment: try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />` to manifest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143858/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-suraj).

Comment: @MohanGopi i m not talking about console.log. Did you debugged it using chrome inspect device option?

Comment: @MohanGopi I dont see READ_SMS permission added in your android manifest in the first place

Comment: @MohanGopi if reading sms is the primary intentm why not use a sms reader cordova plugin available readymade?

Comment: i am not getting you @Gandhi

Comment: @MohanGopi if you trying to read sms, why not use a sms reader plugin?

Comment: ya finally i am able to read the sms in android but the same code is not reading in ios is there any permission for ios @Gandhi

Comment: @MohanGopi did you used sms reader plugin? in ios, its completely different implementation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143875/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-gandhi).

Comment: @Gandhi can you send me the link for ios sms reader plugin

Comment: @MohanGopi Unfortunately no readymade plugin is available and moreover it is not possible too in iOS. As per apple documentation it states 'An iOS app can only access the data for which Apple supplies a documented public API. iOS can not access outside of the sandbox until Apple provides a public API for it. So intercepting/reading an incoming SMS not possible. And no idea when the iOS device is jailbroken.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intent of the requirement is to read SMS, then you can go ahead with readymade [SMS reception plugin](https://github.com/sidchilling/Phonegap-SMS-reception-plugin) or [cordova SMS plugin](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms) available for Android.

But in iOS, SMS reading by an external app is not allowed due to the strict security policy of Apple. You make have to check out this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300138/how-can-we-read-incoming-sms-by-using-application-in-ios) and this [link](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-iOS-not-allow-apps-to-access-SMS-content-on-the-phone) for more info on this.

Hope it helps. Cheers.